# Serialized JSON with double escape character

Tags: c#, json, serialization, escaping

When I tried to serialize an object with a string property containing a slash `/`, the JSON generated escapes twice each slash.

---

**Example:**

A random class:

```
public class Foo
{ 
    [DataMember(Name = "bar"]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
Foo foo = new Foo() { Bar = " Foo / Bar" };
string json = RandomStaticClass.Serialize(foo);
```

The JSON will be:

```
{ 
    \"bar\":\"Foo \\/ Bar\"
}
```

Which results in:

```
{ 
    "bar":"Foo \/ Bar"
}
```

While, I just want:

```
{ 
    "bar":"Foo / Bar"
}
```

Any ideas ? Thanks :)

---

Here is my function to serialize an object :

```
public static string Serialize(object instance)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(instance.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, instance);
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The serializer does this and there isn't an option to turn it off. It's valid JSON, so is there a problem with it being escaped?

Comment: The problem is that the slash is escaped twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you seeing the JSON like this in Visual Studio? Because I believe it is OK like that, while the actual value will not have the escape character.

LE: Tested, you are correct.

I think a workaround might be just to have a Replace call after the string, like this:

```
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(instance.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, instance);
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\\", "");
            }
        }
```

If there is a better option, I would like to know how it's been handled.

I hope this answers your question.

LLE (only if you plan to use this in your client-side with JavaScript):

I have to add the fact that it is automatically done like this (forward slashes are not escaped) to treat closing tags - `/>` (I quote - "HTML does not allow a string inside a  tag to contain `</`"), because in Client-Side `'\/' === '/'` in JavaScript. So you do not have to worry about it.

Comment: I have to add the fact that it is automatically done like this (forward slashes are not escaped) to treat closing tags - "/>" (I quote - "HTML does not allow a string inside a <script> tag to contain </"), because in Client-Side '\/' === '/' in JavaScript. So you do not have to worry about it.

Comment: The main problem when you remove all backslashes is that you may erase backslashes that are actually in the original string.

Comment: But, I can restrict the problem replacing `\/` into `/`.

Comment: That is a solution, too!